# How to check goodness of fit for a graded response model in R

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, item-response-theory

I am using the `grm` function in the `ltm` package in R. There is no function to check the goodness of fit of the output. How can I check if the graded response model is a good fit to the data?

Comment: GoF=goodness of fit, GRM=graded response model, right?

Comment: Yes. that's right

Answer (score 5):

The `ltm` package in R does not have effective global model fit statistics available; one could construct the $G^2$ statistic from the complete-data tables in this package, but this statistic behaves extremely poorly in moderate to large sized tests due to extreme levels of data sparseness. However, the `mirt` package does have suitable limited information tests of overall model fit (version 1.3.3+).

You can call the M2* statistic (Cai and Hansen, 2013) for several polytomous models using the `M2()` function, which collapses the highly sparse complete data tables into first- and second-order information (i.e., means and covariances) to test the goodness of fit based on these marginals instead. For instance,

```
library(mirt)
set.seed(1)
a <- matrix(rlnorm(20))
diffs <- t(apply(matrix(runif(20*4, .3, 1), 20), 1, cumsum)) 
diffs <- -(diffs - rowMeans(diffs)) 
d <- diffs + rnorm(20)

# simulate 20 items, each with 5 ordered categories
dat <- simdata(a, d, N=1000, itemtype = 'graded') 

# estimate the model
mod <- mirt(dat, 1)
Iteration: 63, Log-Lik: -22946.624, Max-Change: 0.00009

# M2() statistic
M2(mod)
           M2  df         p      RMSEA RMSEA_5   RMSEA_95       TLI       CFI      SRMSR
stats 126.155 110 0.1390846 0.01212481       0 0.02091059 0.9955107 0.9962014 0.02216049
```

For further details about this limited-information statistic, see:

Cai, L. & Hansen, M. (2013). Limited-information goodness-of-fit testing of hierarchical item factor models. British Journal of Mathematical and Statistical Psychology, 66, 245-276.